# AngularJS ui-sref links stuck

Tags: javascript, angularjs, anchor

I got an AngularJS based website. Everything is working fine. For navigation I use ui.router.

After I use a lightbox (simplbox.js) links stop working. There is no error message in the log, no warning or anything that indicates that using simplbox and ui.router might cause problems.

Could there be any other reason, why links stop working? If not, how could I debug this?

EDIT:

Once I open and close the simplbox I can use exactly one more link, then links stop working. However, simplbox is still working, as well as other features of the site. "Only" navigation is frozen.

Comment: Could you add plunkr or fiddle?

Comment: Can you clarify upon "the links stop working"?  Are they actually disabled in the browser?  How do they appear when inspecting the page?

Comment: They look as follows: 
<a ui-sref="technology" class="ng-binding" href="#/technology">Technology</a>
The CSS hover effect is still working, but clicking on the link won't do anything. The URL is not changing either.

Comment: You don't need the href attribute, when you're using ui-sref. Make sure you have state called "technology" in $stateProvider's config.

Comment: What I posted is how it looks like once it's rendered. So in my code there is of cause no href. As stated it all works at first, so I know that there is no mistake in my syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that still does not satisfy me entirely. So if anybody can provide some insight I'd be happy to change the accepted answer.

The error was caused by the way I implemented the jquery.min.js. So totally unrelated to angularJS and ionic. First I use a generated cdn code such as

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Back then it was version 2.2.2. What I did was to download the exact same version and include it directly in my index.html.

Changing it back from local to cdn everything works as should do. No problems with the ui-sref links.